# How to delete a line Notepad++ if it contains 2 same characters

Tags: notepad++

I want to delete lines that contain more than one :

From

```
tjeatj:iejta
kmrk:jgors
orksgs:rojsgos:
orskjg:joqe
eijaoeaf:ijfeaf:efaoj
ofkea:oaejf
ekoaf:ofe3okf
```

To

```
tjeatj:iejta
gkmrk:jgors
orskjg:joqe
ofkea:oaejf
ekoaf:ofe3okf
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try finding the following pattern, in regex mode:

```
^.*:.*:.*$\r?\n
```

And then replace with empty string, to effectively remove the contents of the line, and the line ending.